# SendGrid V3 api with C#. email not sending

Tags: c#, sendgrid-api-v3

is there something wrong with this code? I already put my email in my code but I don't get any email.
I have a hint that is it not working because I am using API key ID instead of API key because I can't see my API key because of its only show just once. if is that the reason why is this code not working. Is there no way to view your API key again?

```
   public string SendEmailMain()
        {
            SendEmail().Wait();

        }
 static async Task SendEmail()
        {
            common com = new common();
            var apiKey = com.sendGridAPI;
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("testmail@gmail.com", "test user");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("testemai@gmail.com", "teset user");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";

            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

        }
```

Comment: What response you are getting from sendgrid? If you think API key is the issue then you should get in touch with sendgrid support.

Comment: what response ? i just put the code in my web service when i try to run the function there is no error. but i don't receive any email

Comment: what response ? i just put the code in my web service when i try to run the function there is no error. but i don't receive any email

Comment: `var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);` this response. Did you debug the code and check what value you are getting in `response` variable?

Comment: the return value is "WaitingForActivation"

Comment: i also tried to return response.statuscode and it returns Unauthorized

Comment: In that case you need to check with SendGrid support team. They have nice support system via online chat. It will be quick and they will be able to guide right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code is working pretty well. The thing is i'm using the API key ID because instead of the API key that generated by sendgrid.

[Please refer to this thread for more info](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/278)